# Automatically application deployment with python (by creating Django website)

Tags: scripting, python, local-area-network

I am having 400 machines and all are connected to VPN network and i want to deploy an application(available on server).here challenges is how to collected all real time VPN IP and logic(code) in python??? .

Please let me know if it is possible... any suggestion OR steps.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for deployment automation Ansible will help you.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html